# Using LIKE in SQL with multiple search terms

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, where-clause, sql-like

I'm doing a basic SQL course and learning the basics currently and having issue with filtering:

Task: list all the rows from `TableName` where the `columnName` field content does not contain any of the following words: 'stack' or 'overflow' or 'exampleword'.

```
SELECT columnName 
FROM TableName 
WHERE columnName NOT LIKE '%stack%'
```

-> I get it to work properly with just a single value, but when I try adding more words as values it no longer works ->

```
SELECT columnName 
FROM TableName 
WHERE columnName NOT LIKE '%stack%' OR columnName NOT LIKE '%overflow%'
```

What's the correct syntax for having multiple search terms?

Apparently I'm also not supposed to be using CONTAINS here or it would've been too easy.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server -> We are however trying to use as standard SQL as possible to learn the basics first.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want `AND`, not `OR`:

```
SELECT columnName 
FROM TableName 
WHERE columnName NOT LIKE '%stack%' AND columnName NOT LIKE '%overflow%'
```

You can expand the `WHERE` clause with more conditions as needed.

Side note: if you know in advance in which sequence the words appear in the string, you can also do:

```
SELECT columnName 
FROM TableName 
WHERE columnName NOT LIKE '%stack%overflow%'
```

Comment: @prestige, kindly note that the second statement will only remove records where both "Stack" and "Overflow" are present, unlike the first statement where the record would get removed if either "Stack" or "Overflow" is present. Hope that makes sense